# How to fetch data from Skyscanner?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and there has been a request for grabbing the dynamic data from `www.skyscanner.net`.

Can someone guide me on doing so?

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh

url = 'http://www.skyscanner.net/transport/flights/sin/lhr/131231/140220/'
response = requests.post(url)

tree = lh.document_fromstring(response.content)
print(tree);
```

All I did was to find the pattern in URL and attempt to grab from there. However, no data were successfully pulled. I learnt that Python was the best language in doing such task, but the library seems too huge and I do not know where to start form.

Comment: What is `lh`? Why do you POST?

Comment: Can you not [use their API](http://www.skyscanneraffiliate.net/portal/en-GB/US/api/overview?_ga=1.43727910.208596559.1384787883)?

Comment: have you looked at Beautiful Soup?

Comment: The task requires me to input some search (i suppose) to pull the data out. API is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

My name is Piotr - I work for Skyscanner - in Data Acquisition team - which I assume that you are applying to join :-) As this is a part of your task I wouldn't like to give you a straight answer , however you might consider:

- Understand how our site works - how the requests are built and what data you can find in the http response.
- You could use some libraries that will help you parsing xml/json responses

I think that's all I can say :-)

Cheers,
piotr